# Jenkins build failure,Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, build, daemon

My CI Server configuration is low.

If I use the gradle daemon to build project,It throw a error:

```
* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

Then, If I use the gradle-2.14.1 that default close gradle daemon,my task 'publish' is BUILD SUCCESS, but it will append other task to close daemon that BUILD FAILURE.

```
The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

Of course,if I run the gradle at my macbookpro, everything is OK.

I found the other way to solve the problem, run `gradle --stop`, then run `gradle <task>`. But it just work for simple task.

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: The daemon is not intended for use on CI servers.  There is a warning about that when you use it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the flag `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false` to the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable solved my issue in my case. Details can be found at : 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:ways_to_disable_gradle_daemon

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to turn off gradle daemon on any CI server.

use this option to disable it

--no-daemon

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon

Comment: This appears not to be the case any longer - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2824

Comment: I've just run into this very same issue because of the CI task's container run out of memory. Nothing to do with the daemon itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the following Jenkins Plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle-daemon/ and with the plugin installed, the Daemon is not killed after the build, if it is still in use.